# find col2 values based on certain col1 value, if not presents keep nearest value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1      col2      
 1         10
 2         15
 4         12
 5         23
 6         11
 8         32
 9         12
 11        32
 2         23
 3         21
 4         12
 6         15
 9         12
 10        32
```

I want to select col2 values for every 1, 5 and 10 values of col1. If col1 value is not 1, 5 or 10 keep the col2 values where col1 values is nearest to 1,5 or 10

for example the final df will look like:

```
df
col1      col2      
 1         10
 5         23
 11        32
 2         23
 6         15
 10        32
```

how to do it using pandas without using any loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `df.col1.diff().lt(0).cumsum()` defines groups of ascending values
- `set_index` with those groups **and** `col1` but keep `col1` in the dataframe  proper with `drop=False`
- `groupby` and `pd.concat` to use `reindex` with `method='nearest'`

---

I left the old `col1` index so you can see what got mapped to what.

```
c = df.set_index([df.col1.diff().lt(0).cumsum().rename('grp'), 'col1'], drop=False)
pd.concat([c.xs(k).reindex([1, 5, 10], method='nearest') for k, c in c.groupby(level=0)])

      col1  col2
col1            
1        1    10
5        5    23
10      11    32
1        2    23
5        6    15
10      10    32
```

---

If you don't like that extra `col1` in the index, you can rename the index then drop it:

```
c = df.set_index([df.col1.diff().lt(0).cumsum().rename('grp'), 'col1'], drop=False)
pd.concat([c.xs(k).reindex([1, 5, 10], method='nearest') for k, c in c.groupby(level=0)]) \
    .rename_axis(None).reset_index(drop=True)

   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     5    23
2    11    32
3     2    23
4     6    15
5    10    32
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def extract_vals(x, vals=[1,5,10]):
    vals = np.array(vals)
    s = abs(x['col1'].values - vals[:,None])

    return x.iloc[s.argmin(axis=1)]

s = df.col1.diff().lt(0).cumsum()
df.groupby(s).apply(extract_vals).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output, which is different from yours due to the existence of `4,6` in the second group:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       10
1   5       23
2   9       12
3   2       23
4   4       12
5   10      32
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar with pir's method

```
s=df.col1.diff().lt(0).cumsum()
idx=df.reset_index().groupby(s).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('col1').reindex([1,5,10],method='nearest'))['index']
df.loc[idx]
Out[19]: 
    col1  col2
0      1    10
3      5    23
7     11    32
8      2    23
11     6    15
13    10    32
```

Another way get the index  `merge_asof`

```
df['key']=s
import itertools
l=list(itertools.product(df.key.unique().tolist(),[1,5,10]))
mergedf=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['key','col1']).astype(int)
df.col1=df.col1.astype('int32')
idx=pd.merge_asof(mergedf.sort_values('col1'),df.reset_index().sort_values('col1'),on='col1',by='key',direction ='nearest')['index']
```